# How do I complete the passenger locator form EU for arrival when transiting through Geneva?

Tags: transit, covid-19, eu, geneva

I am trying to complete the French EU passenger locator for a ski holiday where we transit through Geneva and then into France.  Geneva is not coming up as an airport option - Can anybody help?

Comment: are you taking a connecting flight from Geneva to a French airport? If not, EU-PLF is not needed; Swiss PLF is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Geneva isn't an option because it's in Switzerland.

I'm sure you know that already, the point is that the lack of Geneva on the French passenger locator form isn't an error or a problem: You can't arrive in France by air in Geneva*. You're flying to Switzerland, and [must follow the Swiss entry requirements](https://www.gva.ch/en/Site/Passagers/Preparation-voyage/COVID-19/Formalites-Coronavirus-arrivee). Currently:

> Passengers entering Switzerland by air who are not vaccinated or recovered must present the result of a negative PCR test (maximum 72 hours) or antigenic test (maximum 24 hours).
>
> This obligation does not apply to vaccinated or cured persons.

After arriving in Switzerland, you'll then cross the border to France and the [standard entry restrictions](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coming-to-france-your-covid-19-questions-answered/) apply. But you're not arriving by air, so the French procedures for air travel (i.e. passenger locator form) don't apply to you.

*Geneva airport has a French sector, but it's only used for domestic flights and in any case is currently closed.

Answer (score 1):

The French sector of the airport is currently closed for construction. You will leave through Switzerland and enter France by road, as you would probably have done anyway as it's much more convenient if you are going to the Alps and most shuttles leave from the Swiss side.

On the top of that, according to the [FAQ on the website](https://www.gva.ch/fr/Site/Passagers/Questions-Reponses-FAQ/secteur-france#1e1cd060-df7c-4c5f-acd1-15ff59c31d65), the French sector isn't considered French territory for public health purposes. So it seems that as far as France is concerned, you are not entering by air and the obligation does not apply (that's even if you were somehow able to cross to the French sector and take a car or taxi there). And as far as Switzerland is concerned, all the entry rules apply (again, even if your intent is to go to France as fast as possible).